# Vba userform does not allow to open other excel

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please assist me. When I run the userform, it is not allowing to access other existing excel sheet. Is there any solution for this....

I would be really thankfull if someone could assist me.

Comment: You must consider to post the code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Open your VBA project (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>), open UserForm, in properties window change `ShowModal` property from `True` to `False`:

[image: UserForm properties window]

If you show the userform runtime within your code, then use:

```
UserForm1.Show False
```